# Spring Boot Scheduler fixedDelay and cron

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduler

I'm running a spring boot scheduled process that takes 5-10 seconds to complete.  After it completes, 60 seconds elapse before the process begins again (Note that I'm not using fixedRate):

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=60_000)
```

Now, I want to limit it to run every minute Mon-Fri 9am to 5pm.  I can accomplish this with

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 * 9-16 ? * MON-FRI")
```

Problem here is that this acts similar to fixedRate - the process triggers EVERY 60 seconds regardless of the amount of time it took to complete the previous run...

Any way to to combine the two techniques?

Comment: Please see this [article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks)

Comment: It seem your target is conflicted, fixedDelay and fixedRate(cron) can't achieve at the same time. If you start a job at the begin of each minute and the task take 90s to finish, how can you achieve it?

Comment: I read the question to clearly say that fixed rate is exactly not the target. Indeed it describes that as the undesired behaviour. @huy

Comment: Tom D, trying to clarify the phrasing. By "I want to limit it to run every minute Mon-Fri 9am to 5pm." I think you mean "I want it to execute with 60 second delay, but only Mon-Fri 9am to 5pm". Can you confirm?

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me like this

I created a bean that returns a specific task executor and allowed only 1 thread.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Bean(name = "movProcTPTE")
    public TaskExecutor movProcessualThreadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor exec = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        exec.setMaxPoolSize(1);
        exec.initialize();
        return exec;
    }
}
```

In my service, I injected my task executor and wrapped my logic with it, so even though my schedule runs every minute, my logic will only run when the task executor is free.

```
@Service
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduledService {

    @Autowired
    private ReportDataService reportDataService;

    @Autowired
    private AsyncService async;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("movProcTPTE")
    private TaskExecutor movProcTaskExecutor;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * 1-7 * SAT,SUN")
    public void agendamentoImportacaoMovProcessual(){
        movProcTaskExecutor.execute(
                () -> {
                    reportDataService.importDataFromSaj();
                }
        );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Schedules({ 
  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000), 
  @Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * *")
})
```

Comment: Try to add some description with your code. What is does? how it solve the problem ?

Comment: Found it mentioned at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduling-annotations#schedules as well and at another stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297213/spring-boot-job-scheduler-fixeddelay-and-cron . From the baeldung article, I assume one can use fixedDelay instead of the fixedRate and achieve what OP wanted - fixedDelay + cron.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one:
@Scheduled(cron="1 9-16 * * MON-FRI")

---

Also you can try write correct on this site https://crontab.guru/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Does this implement a fixed rate, every minute? If not and it gets instead execution with a delay of 60 seconds between finishing and restart (which I think is what OP wants), then please explain how that is achieved - because I doubt it. Note OPs phrase "Problem here is that this ... triggers EVERY 60 seconds". Clearly that is not what OP wants, even if I misread the actual goal.

Answer (score -3):

You can pass fixed delay (and any other number of optional parameters) to the annotation, like so:

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 * 9-16 ? * MON-FRI", fixedDelay=60_000)
```

From the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html

Comment: Thanks for your response Andonaeus, but this didn't work for me, I get error:
Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'execute': **Exactly** one of the 'cron', 'fixedDelay(String)', or 'fixedRate(String)' attributes is required

FYI I'm using version 2.0.0.RELEASE

Comment: Strnagely enough this document says quite the opposite:
An annotation that marks a method to be scheduled. Exactly one of the cron(), fixedDelay(), or fixedRate() attributes must be specified.

Comment: At a time only one can be used from following   : cron(), fixDelay(), fixRate(). . However by default scheduler is not "async" in behavior means if a task is executing, another will not be executed until last is finished.