# Spring Boot Job Scheduler fixedDelay and cron

Tags: java, cron, scheduler

I'm running a spring boot scheduled process that takes 5-10 seconds to complete. After it completes, 60 seconds elapse before the process begins again (Note that I'm not using fixedRate):

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=60_000)
```

N
ow, I want to limit it to run every minute Mon-Fri 9am to 5pm. I can accomplish this with

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 * 9-16 ? * MON-FRI")
```

Problem here is that this acts similar to fixedRate - the process triggers EVERY 60 seconds regardless of the amount of time it took to complete the previous run...

Any way to to combine the two techniques?

Comment: what do you mean by combining the two techniques ? can you explain what exact behaviour you want ?

Comment: For example the scheduler should get invoked at a particular time say 9am to 5pm to pick a particular batch and process. But what Fixed delay does is as soon as the first batch is done processing the next batch would be picked up for processing but this need to be done with limit that it should be inviked only between  9am to 5pm.

Comment: I noticed that when I start a cron that's already running it will run again. For example: I have a task that takes 15 minutes, but the cron executes it's every 5 minutes. In the database the cron gets the status running and the other scheduled jobs have pending. But after 5 minutes, the other job (with the same code) also starts to run. So now I have the same job running twice! So to avoid that I wanted to use fixedDelay

Comment: what you can do is..Run the jobs at particular times and create a timestamp file when your job is invoked and before running next jobs check that the current time has passed the delay from the timestamp. If not then dont run the next job. (this is a workaround, but i guess you can not do that through crontab)

Comment: though in case when you know that your job is taking approx 15 minutes, you should not run crons every 5 minutes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot Scheduler fixedDelay and cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372127/spring-boot-scheduler-fixeddelay-and-cron)

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
@Schedules({ 
  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000), 
  @Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * *")
})
```

Comment: Requires at least spring-context 4.0 but IMHO this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Found it mentioned at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduling-annotations#schedules as well. From the baeldung article, I assume one can use fixedDelay instead of the fixedRate and achieve what OP wanted - fixedDelay + cron.

Comment: @yasd not necessarily - OP seems to want to use fixedDelay, not fixedRate. Though it should be achievable by just replacing fixedRate with fixedDelay in the suggested code. For more info, see my earlier comment.